# Trigger a function upon receiving POST

Tags: php, jquery, post

Is there a way to trigger a function when a $_POST is received?

I have a php page that finishes executing and calls another page. The other page performs certain actions and POST updates back to this page. I need to be able to update a div as and when a POST is received.

Making an ajax request and using "success" callback as a trigger doesn't work since this will update my div ONLY ONCE. The problem is that this page will receive POST multiple times at irregular intervals and I need a way to trigger an action whenever POST is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ajax (I'd use jQuery) and set a time interval to check if there was a status change. The "other page" should not post back to the first page, but save data in a "requestable" area (might be an database, a file etc) where this new info/status will be stored and retrieved periodically by the Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

usually, I would do something like this...

`$var_posted=0;`

`if($_POST['var']){$var_posted=1;}`

then...

`if($var_posted==1){some_function();}`

Comment: Of course one should mention that this is **extremely** bad idea if someone had previously another extremely bad idea of turning on the `register_globals` directive ([see more](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) - especially Example #1 of misuse, which is actually almost identicall to CheeseConQueso's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX, because you can't trigger `$_POST` recieving in php,
As I understand you just need to update some `<div>` inner html after post is recieved, and you are able to do it with jQuery [events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the following way (below is the PHP code, just FYI):

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // do whatever you mean by 'updating the div'
}
```

However AJAX may be more appropriate and it is (believe or not) more flexible.

AJAX call will be smaller load on your server and can update the box single or multiple times (depending on how you write the JS code) - in such case I recommend using jQuery for simplicity (if you are not familiar with JS).